# Searching for a 3 digit number in a text line in python

Tags: python

I have a long text line with a lot of random words and numbers, i wish to assign a variable to the only 3 digit number in the line.

The number changes every different line but it is always only 3 digits. How does one search for the only 3 digit number in a linepython? There may be some 3 letter words so it must just be the number.

```
09824747 18 n 02 archer 0 bowman 0 003 @ 09640897 n 0000
```

in this example i want the variable digits = 003

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A regular expression with `\b` word boundaries would do the trick:

```
re.findall(r'\b\d{3}\b', inputtext)
```

returns a list of all 3-digit numbers.

Demo:

```
>>> import re
>>> inputtext = '09824747 18 n 02 archer 0 bowman 0 003 @ 09640897 n 0000'
>>> re.findall(r'\b\d{3}\b', inputtext)
['003']
>>> inputtext = 'exact: 444, short: 12, long: 1234, at the end of the line: 456'
>>> re.findall(r'\b\d{3}\b', inputtext)
['444', '456']
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use regular expressions. Or look for a digit, then check the next two characters manually.

I would use a regexp:

```
import re

threedig = re.compile(r'\b(\d{3})\b') # Regular expression matching three digits.
```

The `\b` means "word boundary", and `(\d{3})` means "three digits", the parenthesis makes it a "group" so the matching text can be found.

Then search using:

```
mo = threedig.search("09824747 18 n 02 archer 0 bowman 0 003 @ 09640897 n 0000")
if mo:
  print mo.group(1)
```

The above prints `333`.

Comment: I didn't know this `\b`, very useful !

Comment: The parenthesis are not needed at all; the `\b` boundary matches a *location*, not any characters. As such, the grouping isn't needed because there is nothing to distinguish the digits from.

Answer (score 0):

A solution thanks to regular expressions:

```
>>> s = "007 09824747 18 n 02 archer 0 bowman 0 003 @ 09640897 n 0000 008"
>>> r = re.findall(r'(?:[^\d]|\A)(\d{3})(?:[^\d]|\Z)', s)
>>> r
['007', '003', '008']
```

Answer (score 0):

In Python, I got the following to work (based on the answers above):

```
re.compile('prefix\d{1,3}\suffix')})
```

This covers the scenario for **anywhere between 1-3 digits**